# Some requests still going to the 'default' module, not all

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm switching an existing python appengine app to 'modules' -- so I can serve user-facing web pages with different servers than those serving API calls.

Here's my dispatch file (as copied from the dispatch link in the appengine UI)

```
Dispatch    Target Module
*/api*  backend-module
*/ae*   backend-module
*/adddata   backend-module
*/tasks*    backend-module
*/crons*    backend-module
```

Suprisingly, calls to /tasks/blahblah and /crons/blahblah go to the backend-module, while calls to /api/blahblah and /ae/blahblah go to the default module!

Since calls to /tasks and /crons are actually kicked off from within appengine python code, I think this has to do with my domain setup or something? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Again, I want calls to www.mydomain.com/api/blahblah to go to the backend server, but for some reason they're still going to my default module.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: requests to myappid.appspot.com/api go to the backend module, while requests to www.mydomain.com/api go to the default module.  It's something with my domain setup, but my domain works great normally and with https:// so I'm not sure what's up.

Comment: I'd also try `*/api/*` instead of `*/api*`. I *vaguely* remember some unexpected difference in behaviour with the 2 patterns for URLs that were apparently matching both but I don't recall if it was for rules in the dispatch file or some other path-matching rules. Can't easily check anymore since I switched to hostname-based routing since.

Comment: So I think I have narrowed this down to the fact that I have myapp.appspot.com, and myapp-hrd.appspot.com.  The domain is setup via google apps to forward everything to myapp.appspot.com, which is an alias for myapp-hrd.appspot.com. I think this is causing the issue, otherwise I can't explain it.  at the moment, myapp.appspot.com/api/download DOES go to backend-module, and so does myapp-hrd.appspot.com/api/download, so it has to be a domain related issue...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it had to do with domain settings in my google apps account. I had http**s**://www going to myapp -- once I pointed http://www to myapp-hrd that fixed things.